# kotlin - Unresolved reference: spinnerCourses

Tags: android, kotlin

Please help, Im new to kotlin.
I added a spinner in the Layout file and created an adapter in the MainActivity but im getting this error **Unresolved reference: spinnerCourses**
Here is the code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    val dm = DataManager()
    val adapterCourses = ArrayAdapter<CourseInfo>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    dm.courses.values.toList())
    adapterCourses.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

    spinnerCourses.adapter = adapterCourses



}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> true
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

}

[image: main activity]
[image: This is the layout file]

Comment: You haven't declared `spinnerCourses` anywhere, so the error makes sense. Unless you're trying to use Kotlin synthetic bindings? In which case these have been deprecated for a long time now, I would look into view/data binding!

Comment: Why are you not instantiating the binding class? Also are you using [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) or [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)?

Comment: If you're not familiar with ViewBinding or DataBinding , I would recommend the older the `findViewById<View>` method. However it's high time you consider moving to ViewBinding or DataBinding

Comment: Thank you for your help, i was using kotlin synthetic bindings. i looked into view&data binding. used view binding and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin synthetic bindings are deprecated, used view binding and it worked like a charm